# MongoDb complex query: How to query some "Page"s out of "Book"s belonging to a "User"

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

I designed the schemas much like a relational database. Like so:

```
User
  user_id: String
  ...

Book
  user_id: String
  book_id: String
  ...

Page
  book_id: String
  page_id: String
  ...
```

Because a User can have many many books, and a Book has many pages.

Now I want to query the first 5 pages of the first 25 books of a user. How would I do that in MongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, MongoDB doesn't really have 'relational' features like MySQL/etc have. So you need to fetch the data using multiple queries by first getting your user's id, then finding books like `db.books.find({ "user_id": uid }).limit(25)`, then using that to go through each book to similarly find the first 5 pages of each.

Alternatively you could embed the pages into the book, but then we get into a whole other story about how to optimize the querying :)